# How many warning signals are voiced in modern airliners?

Tags: airliner, cockpit

Some warning signal in modern airliners are voiced, like [TCAS warning](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lHXk0KsRHmg) and [GPWS warning (PULL UP!)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rpcfTX7qf8Y).

And how many warning signal are voiced in the modern airliners?

Moreover, where is the sound produced?

Comment: A voice warning would have been helpful on [Helios flight 522](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helios_Airways_Flight_522)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Modern airliners have voice warnings in a number of systems like,

- Ground Proximity Warning System
- Terrain Collision Avoidance System
- Windshear Alerts
- Radio Altitude callouts
- Trim
- Fire Detection
- Autopilot configuration
- Pressurization systems
- Landing gear system
- Stall/overspeed warning.

The amount of voice warnings vary from aircraft to aircraft. For example, [airliners.net](http://www.airliners.net/aviation-forums/tech_ops/read.main/246525/) has the following list of voice warnings in Bombardier CRJ-200 (other than GPWS and TCAS):

> "APU" APU overspeed or overtemp
>
> "Door" open or unsafe passenger door indication
>
> "Jetpipe Overheat" overheat indication in jetpipe/pylon
>
> "Smoke" smoke detected in cargo area of lavatory
>
> "Config Autopilot/Flaps/Spoilers/Trim/Brakes" Aircraft not properly 
>   configured for takeoff
>
> "Wing Overheat" Overheat in fuselage wing anti-ice ducts
>
> "Anti-ice Duct" Bleed air leak in fuselage or wing anti-ice ducts
>
> "Bleed Air Duct" leak in different part of bleed air duct system
>
> "Brakes" brake overheat
>
> "Config Brakes" here again because it's for having the parking brake set 
>   while airborne
>
> "Gear Disagree" disagreement between gear indications and handle position
>
> "Gear Bay Overheat" overheat in main gear bay
>
> "Nose Door" Nose gear door open after gear fully extended and locked or >250 
>   knots
>
> "Engine Oil" oil pressure <25 psi

Initially, most of the voice warnings were recorded voices. However, more and more modern systems (like in newer 737s) are using computer generated voices.

Comment: Do you have any further reading about the modern computer generated voices for airliners?